# How to require a user to get authenticated in a live view, via a plug or an anternative?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this live view wherein I'm trying to do a plug which I've used in other, non-live, parts of my application:

```elixir
defmodule MyApp123Web.MyLive do
  use MyApp123Web, :live_view

  # TODO
  plug MyApp123Web.RequireAuthentication

===>

** (CompileError): undefined function plug/1 (there is no such import)
```

Is this a right approach for a live view in the first place?
If not, how would it have to be implemented for a live view **in a simple way**?

My plug is this:

```elixir
defmodule MyApp123Web.RequireAuthentication do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(options), do: options

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    user = conn.assigns[:current_user]
    if is_nil(user) do
      |> Phoenix.Controller.redirect(conn, to: "/login")
      |> halt()
    else
      conn
    end
  end
end
```

**update 1**

I have a few existing non-live routes, or a scope, that requires authentication already. How to incorporate the live-view ones with those?

```elixir
  scope "/my", App123Web, as: :my do
    pipe_through [:browser, :csrf, :require_authentication]

    get "/", My.DashboardController, :index
    get "/index", My.DashboardController, :index2

    # ???
    live_session ???? do
      ???
    end
```

Will a `live_session` inside this `scope` even have to be require authentication itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in [this guide](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/security-model.html), a plug isn't enough for a liveview and you also need to check authentication on mount:

> LiveView begins its life-cycle as a regular HTTP request. Then a stateful connection is established. Both the HTTP request and the stateful connection receive the client data via parameters and session.
> This means that any session validation must happen both in the HTTP request (plug pipeline) and the stateful connection (LiveView mount).

As explained in this same article, you can define a reusable mount hook like:

```elixir
defmodule MyAppWeb.UserLiveAuth do
  import Phoenix.LiveView

  def on_mount(:default, _params, %{"user_id" => user_id} = _session, socket) do
    socket = assign_new(socket, :current_user, fn ->
      Accounts.get_user!(user_id)
    end)

    if socket.assigns.current_user.confirmed_at do
      {:cont, socket}
    else
      {:halt, redirect(socket, to: "/login")}
    end
  end
end
```

This hook can then simply be used either directly in your live view using [`Phoenix.LiveView.on_mount/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#on_mount/1), or in the router with [`Phoenix.LiveView.Router.live_session/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.Router.html#live_session/3):

```elixir
  live_session :default, on_mount: MyAppWeb.UserLiveAuth do
    live "/foo", FooLive, :index
  end
```

Comment: Ok. But how would I incorporate this with an existing normal `scrope` where there're only standard, non-live routes and controllers? Let's say, I have `scope /my/` which uses pipeline `auth_required` already, via a plug.

Comment: As you can see in the examples live session can be used inside a scope

Comment: But that's how I'd used it, and am using, before posting my question. Nonetheless, an unauthenticated user still could go a live page.

Comment: Or you imply that there has to be 2 conditions: 1) authentication by `scope` via pipeline 2) authentication by `live_session` via `on_mount` too?

Comment: Basically yes, what the doc says is that both need to be checked. This [article](https://blog.appsignal.com/2022/01/25/securing-your-phoenix-liveview-apps.html) might help, it is presenting the whole thing together.